# DNS and Http HOST header issue

Tags: http, sharepoint-2007, dns, windows-server-2008

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am using publishing portal template. I have a physical server with a single IP address, and I have set in DNS to map two domain names (server1.mycorp.com and server2.mycorp.com) to the same server/IP address.

My question is how to setup two SharePoint web sites on the same server with a single IP address to serve two domain names individually (with the same port number 80)? My current idea is to create two SharePoint web applications for the two web sites, with the same port number 80, but with different host header (setup Http host header to server1.mycorp.com and server2.mycorp.com individually for the two SharePoint web applications). Not sure whether my idea is feasible?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this belongs in ServerFault.

And you also seem to describe a common host header concept, when you create your WebApplication in the SharePoint Central Admin, you will define a host header, being on the same IP or not, IIS will respond to them individually, so yes it works.

Application Management => Create Web Application => define host header, define same port 80, done.

Comment: 1. Is my solution correct? 2. When user type "http://server1.mycorp.com/default.aspx", then the host header will be server1.mycorp.com, and when user type "http://server2.mycorp.com/default.aspx", then the host header will be server1.mycorp.com?

Comment: If you want multiple Hosts for a same website with different configurations (i.e.: authentication) you make use of the Zones concept, to do that you go to Application Management => Create or Extend Web Application => Extend an existing Web application. To have multiple hosts respond to an IP with the exact same website opening you have to use the Alternate URL Mappings concept. To use that go to Operations => Alternate Access Mappings